# Adding a WPF User Control from Code Behind

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a `UserControl` that I want to add at runtime to my current WPF Page. Is this possible?

Having a `Menu-bar` and under it i want to have all my information, i.e. that i select `Menu -> Show Orders` then I want the `OrderList-UserControl` to be added under the `Menu`.

Sure I could use an Order WPF Page for that but then I'd have to re-create the `Menu` everywhere? And I don't like the redundancy in that.

I tried something like this which didn't display anything at all, it sure did run the code inside the `UserControl` but nothing is displayed on my window:

```
wrapPanel1.Children.Add(new OrderControl(100));
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put a ContentPresenter as a placeholder you can set the Content property of that control to a control generated in codebehind.

---

Strange, looking at the code in [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel.aspx) what you are doing should work correctly - and the code I gave you definitely works in my app - so I guess there is something wrong either with your custom control or the screen redraws. Can you add the control directly in XMAL and see it? What happens if you add the control through code behind then force a screen redraw (cover the window with another and then uncover it).