# Add button in App.xaml and add it programatically in other xaml pages Windows Runtime apps

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I want to add control (like button, textboxes, etc.) in App.xaml and access it from other xaml pages and add them programmatically.

I want to make that xaml control in App.xaml global so that I can access it from any other pages.

Any idea on this how to implement such scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

First to add a user control in your project and then perform action whatever you want in c#(like BottomAppBaras user control).

then add that control in any page where you want.

Code:In two steps

1. Create a user control
2. put this code where you want your user control.Just change user control name as per your user control name.

if you want to add through pragmatically then follow this link
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32825/How-to-Creating-a-WPF-User-Control-using-it-in-a-W

Comment: Hi, Can you please add some reference links.?

Comment: Follow on this link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410263/adding-a-wpf-user-control-from-code-behind"

Comment: Hi, I am still confused here. I want to add controls in App.xaml and access it in MainPage.xaml. I assume we can do something like this `Template = (ControlTemplate)Application.Current.Resources["appButtonStyle"];` but gets some error using this.

Comment: @KishorBikramOli: I understand your problem but i  can't reproduce your problem and please provide a proper description for this question and also provide your code so any one can test your code and give you a proper answer.

Comment: Hi Can you please refer this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38184819/no-installed-components-were-detected-element-is-already-the-child-of-another-e